# User Authentication Dlookup [Access 07 VBA]

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to make a user authentication system for my access database. currently I have a form which has two combo boxes "Username" and "Password" 
and a button used to authenticate entered data. I also have a table named "Login" which houses all of the usernames and passwords and also their "Level" which is their clearance level which will determine which version of a form opens as well as other information. I am not proficient at Dlookup and I am getting an error "Invalid outside procedure" Can I not pass the dlookup value as a string that can be used in an if statement?

CODE:

```vb
Public Sub Command4_Click()
    Dim usr As String
    Dim lvl As String
    Dim lck As Integer

    usr = DLookup("Password", "Login", "Me.Username.Value= 'Username'")
    lvl = DLookup("Level", "Login", "Me.Username.Value= 'Username'")

    If usr = Me.Password.Value Then lck = 1

    Do While lck = 1
        If lvl = 3 Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Main"
            lck = 0
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Which code line is highlighted when you get that error?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no debug info that is brought up. just the error:     "The expression on click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: Invalid outside procedure."

Comment: Make sure you have `Option Explicit` in the module's Declarations section.  Then run Debug->Compile from the VB editor's main menu.  `Dim usr As sting` should trigger a compile error, *"User-defined type not defined"*.  Change that to `As String` and try compile again.

Comment: Alright fixed the declare statement (String and Option Explicit). After compiling and running the code again I get "Variable not defined" on `Main` of `DoCmd.OpenForm (Main)` and I do indeed have that form in my DB.

Comment: Good!  Now fix that.  `OpenForm` expects a string value for the form name, and don't include parentheses there: `DoCmd.OpenForm "Main"`

Comment: Got that working. Now I just need to fix the Runtime Error 3125 which is on `DLookup("[Password]", "Login", "[Me.Username.Value]= '" & [Username] & "'")` which says _" is not a valid name_

Comment: OK, I updated the question with the code changes I think you're using now.  Please fix anything I got wrong.  For the `DLookup`, try asdev's suggestion with the quotes: `DLookup("[Password]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'")`

Comment: Awesome. Everything is mostly working as intended. I will update the code soon so everyone can have a simple solution to this issue.

Comment: That is encouraging.  :-)  If you show us your solution, please submit it as an answer instead of adding it to the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
usr = DLookup("[Password]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'" )
lvl = DLookup("[Level]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'")
```

See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US for more Info.

Comment: As you allude to, I'm pretty sure the single quotes will be needed as well `"[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'"`

Comment: Edited as from @Matt Hall suggested

Answer (score 1):

After much help from HansUp Sensei and the crucial addition from asdev I have completed the working code for a simple user authentication form based on a table. You can add levels and modify the `If` statement to assign appropriate access to areas of the database.

```
 Public Sub Command4_Click()

Dim usr As String
Dim lvl As String
Dim lck As Integer

usr = DLookup("[Password]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'")
lvl = DLookup("[Level]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'")

If usr = Me.Password.Value Then
lck = 1
Else
MsgBox ("Invalid Credentials")
End If

Do While lck = 1
    If lvl = "3" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Main"
        lck = 0
    End If
Loop
```

`End Sub`